# Adding template to admin panel results in strange behaviour

Tags: admin, layout, template, render

I am having some problems with adding files to the admin/sales_order_create/index page in Magento's admin/backend section. The js file is being rendered but twice. This is definitely not being called from anywhere else because if I comment it out from the layout file it's not even rendered once.

The phtml template doesn't render at all but when I put a javascript alert in it for some reason the alert popped up on page load. When this happened I added some markup to see if that would render also but it didn't despite the alert showing.

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mto.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
         <reference name="head">
             <action method="addItem">
                 <type>skin_js</type>
                 <name>mto/js/createOrder.js</name>
             </action>
         </reference>
         <reference name="content">
             <block type="adminhtml/template" name="search" template="mto/index.phtml"/>
         </reference>
   </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mto/index.phtml

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get everything to load as it should (only once) and it all seems to work. I have had difficulty getting the template to render at my chosen part of the page as only one method that I have tried seemed to work but I might be able to do something with javascript.

This is my updated layout file.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>


    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>mto/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>mto/js/jquery-ui.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>mto/js/createOrder.js</name>
        </action>


    </reference>

    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="primaCustomer" template="mto/index.phtml"/>
    </reference>



</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>

<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_header>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>mto/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>mto/js/jquery-ui.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>mto/js/createOrder.js</name>
        </action>


    </reference>

    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="primaCustomer" template="mto/index.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_header>
</layout>
```